# Window with activity in GNOME, notifies but doesn't show itself after Alt+Tab?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, gnome-shell, gdm

When a process that has an open window is activated, it remains un-focused and hidden underneath other windows but gives a small notification below that there was action.  This is particularly evident in these situations:

- **PCManFM File Manager** - when it is already open to a folder and is given a new
  one to open into a new tab
- **File-Roller** or **Archive Manager** - when it has a file open already and gets a
  new one and opens in a window.

I use **Gnome 3.x** primarily.  I've scoured to the end and back of `dconf` 30 times and the closest I could find was `focus_mode = click` and `auto_raise = true` but neither had any effect.

I've been at this so long I'm bound to be overlooking something.  Feel free to set me straight if you see something blatant I'm missing.  **Here's the system setup:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 x64 (and Fedora 20)
- Gnome 3.x (all versions affected)
- AMD Catalyst 13 drivers for Radeon R9
- `gdm`

#### EDIT #1

`nautilus` is affected by this as well I just confirmed.

I really need these windows to show up when stuff happens.  Especially because *I'm the one making the stuff happen*, not some random process.

Gladly will post any settings or config files as desired.

#### EDIT #2

I have narrowed the action responsible down to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (even when re-assigned to a new key mapping **AND** when another mapping with a similar action is re-assigned to it).

At first I thought it could be the **Alternate Tab** extension but disabling that did *nothing*.

To replicate:  Open a files window, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to another window and then open another instance of the file manager.  It doesn't have to be in a tab; *it will occur with a new window as well.*

Comment: Just confirming that this behavior is indeed the default one for me as well. I'm using GNOME 3.8 as well as Nautilus on Fedora 19.

Comment: Have you tried these suggestions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/80969/sometimes-new-windows-dont-come-to-the-front-when-launched

Comment: Sadly the extension on the page doesn't work and the accepted answer seems not to apply since I don't even use metacity (not a listed item in `gconf`)

Comment: @slm PS - not using metacity or compiz

Comment: Not finding much else for this, I might be inclined to see if I was able to fix the extension myself using it as a base if it's annoying me enough 8-). Asking this in an official GNOME forum/bugtracker would be my next step too.

Comment: @don_crissti I was so excited when this actually worked for `file-roller` but then...does nothing for the folders that open.  It is a big step in the right direction at least.  If I could give you half the bounty for half the answer I would lol.  PS - altered this line in all `pcmanfm*.desktop` and `nautilus*.desktop` files, just to be safe.  According to the spec, it centers around new window vs new process and the action doesn't create a window but a tab inside the existing window.  Thanks for the hep so far though I appreciate it.

Comment: What is your Window Manager??

Comment: @don_crissti I'm about to use this right now wish me luck.  The code looks promising.

Comment: @don_crissti that...was EXACTLY what I've been looking for.  it's almost sad how happy I am that you posted that.  Please put that into an answer so I can accept and award you the bounty so others may find the answer to this question easier than I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some apps (e.g. `file-roller`) this can be fixed by changing the `StartupNotify` key value from `true` to `false` in their respective `.desktop` files (e.g. `/usr/share/applications/file-roller.desktop`).

The above doesn't work for all apps (e.g. `nautilus`) so another way to fix the problem would be a custom shell extension; just to give you an idea, you could easily fix `nautilus` behavior like this: edit `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/windowAttentionHandler.js` and add these three lines of code:

```
    if (app.get_id() == "nautilus.desktop")
        Main.activateWindow(window);
        return;
```

after the following line:

```
    let app = this._tracker.get_window_app(window);
```

so you end up with something like this:

```
    let app = this._tracker.get_window_app(window);
    if (app.get_id() == "nautilus.desktop")
        Main.activateWindow(window);
        return;
    let source = new Source(app, window);
    Main.messageTray.add(source);
```

However, it's not worth writing your own extension unless you want to target only some specific applications.  For a global change it looks like there is an extension:

[just show the window](https://github.com/ryanlerch/gnome-shell-extension-justshowthewindow)

that overrides the "notification system" (it works fine here on `gnome 3.8`).
Keep in mind the two files (`extension.js` and `metadata.json`) have to be placed in:
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/justshowthewindow@ryanlerch.org`
Activate the extension via tweak-tool and restart the shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: it blows my mind that this is so hard to accomplish without knowledge of gnome-shell inner-workings and/or extension development.  Super freaking glad to be rid of the issue though.  Thanks again my sanity owes you big time.

Comment: @Deryck - starting with Gnome 3.12 one will no longer be able to hack shell `js` files for a quick fix: the [shell will be a single binary](http://worldofgnome.org/shell-is-turned-into-a-binary-performance-optimizations-gnome-3-12/) and as such the only way to customize it will be via extensions. Just so you know...

Answer (score 0):

this issue has appeared in other forums on different versions of Ubuntu and people using gnome. the easiest way to fix the issue is make sure that you have Compiz Config Settings Manager installed.

sometimes the install never is done right and the manager has to be re installed.

to install it search for compizconfig-settings-manager in Software Center and install from there
or type in your terminal `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

once that is done go to system tools > preferences > compizconfig

Go at the very bottom where it says windows management and put a check mark in it. that should fix the problem

Comment: I will test this on my laptop with a new install first but even if it helps, installing compiz is quite a drastic step to take for such a ***small*** (yet incredibly painful) issue.  Thanks for the idea I'll let you know if it helps.

Comment: I have found the answer in the comment by @don_crissti.  Thank you for your post.